# Call variables POST in loop PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I am dynamically adding inputs and texts (code in JavaScript). I have to add all the texts from  fields to the database(MySQL). I don't know how to connect JS and PHP in this situation.
Adding inputs works. My problem is with adding value dynamically to the database form the inputs.

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var lp=2;
  //var lp = "<?= $liczba; ?>";
function dodaj_odpowiedz(kontener){

  var kontener = document.getElementById(kontener);

  var znacznik = document.createElement('input');
  znacznik.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  znacznik.setAttribute('name', 'odp'+lp);
  znacznik.setAttribute('id', 'odp'+lp);
  znacznik.className = 'upload';
  znacznik.setAttribute('size', '40');
  kontener.appendChild(znacznik);

  var znacznik2 = document.createElement('input');
  znacznik2.setAttribute('type', 'button');
  znacznik2.setAttribute('name', 'usuwanie'+lp);
  znacznik2.setAttribute('id', 'usun'+lp);
  znacznik.className = 'upload';
  var funkcja = "usun('"+lp+"')";
  znacznik2.setAttribute('onclick', funkcja);
  znacznik2.setAttribute('value', 'Usun');

 // document.write(znacznik2 . "<br>");
  kontener.appendChild(znacznik2); 
   lp++;
}

function usun(id){

        $("#odp"+id).remove();
        $("#usun"+id).remove();

  }

</script>
```

PHP:

```
                $liczba = "<script language='javascript'>document.write(lp);</script>"; 
                echo 'ilosc: '.$liczba;
                for ($i=2; $i <= $liczba ; $i++) 
                { 
                $odpowiedz2 = $_POST['odp".$i."'];
                $sql_wprowadz_odpowiedz="INSERT INTO odpowiedzi (Tresc_odpowiedzi, Poprawnosc, ID_pytania) VALUES ('$odpowiedz2', NULL, '$row[ID_pytania]')";  //dodawanie kolejnych odpowiedzi do bazy
                mysqli_query($sqlc,$sql_wprowadz_odpowiedz);
                }
```

So, how can I add texts from inputs to database in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `var lp` value is not posted/saved when the form is submitted, so this

```
$liczba = "<script language='javascript'>document.write(lp);</script>"; 
echo 'ilosc: '.$liczba;
```

will not do what you expected.

Try changing your php to something like

```
// use pre_grep() to find match all the input=odp*, and use count() to get total, and add 1 since you are starting from opd2
$liczba = count(preg_grep('/^odp[\d]*/', array_keys($_POST)))+1;

for ($i=2; $i <= $liczba; $i++) {

     //always sanitize your user data
     $odpowiedz2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($sqlc,$_POST["odp".$i]);

     $sql_wprowadz_odpowiedz="INSERT INTO odpowiedzi (Tresc_odpowiedzi, Poprawnosc, ID_pytania) VALUES ('$odpowiedz2', NULL, '$row[ID_pytania]')";  //dodawanie kolejnych odpowiedzi do bazy

     mysqli_query($sqlc,$sql_wprowadz_odpowiedz);
}
```

Comment: Working ! Thank youuu vary much !

Comment: glad that I was able to help. make sure to mark the answer so it will close the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Dont append a number to the textfield! Thats hard to work with.
Just name all your fields as
`name[]`
then you will get them in `$_POST['name']` as array.